# A math puzzle.... what is the solution?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

I have some addition problems to show you...

*15 + 37 = 16*
*24 + 56 = 7*
*35 + 64 = 18*
*43 + 123 = 3*
*81 + 251 = n*

Based on the answers I've already given you, **can you figure out the value of *n*?**

Comment: This post is less of a math puzzle, and more of a "I'll give you these math problems with no clues and expect you to solve them" type of deal. -1

Comment: And the fact that OP is too lazy to even type things..

Comment: The answer is 42

Answer (score 3):

Answer is

> 332

since

> that is what 81+251 equals and there is nothing in the question that states we can't just solve the equation like we normally would.  Obviously the person who solved the first questions wasn't very good at math.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is

> Either $7$ or $17$
>  (I imagine the source was multiple choice and has only one of these as an option)

Because

> If we sum the digits and subtract $10$ from the **odd results**: 
>  \begin{align}15+37\rightarrow1+5+3+7&=16&=16\\24+56\rightarrow2+4+5+6&=17\rightarrow17-10&=7\\35+64\rightarrow3+5+6+4&=18&=18\\43+123\rightarrow4+3+1+2+3&=13\rightarrow13-10&=3\\81+251\rightarrow8+1+2+5+1&=17\rightarrow17-10&=7\end{align}
>  If we sum the digits and subtract $10$ from the **even entries**: \begin{align}15+37\rightarrow1+5+3+7&&=16\\24+56\rightarrow2+4+5+6&-10&=7\\35+64\rightarrow3+5+6+4&&=18\\43+123\rightarrow4+3+1+2+3&-10&=3\\81+251\rightarrow8+1+2+5+1&&=17\end{align}

Comment: I think you're on the right track,